# How to fix "unsafe-eval" error with Vue3 for the client-side version?

Tags: javascript, express, vuejs3, content-security-policy

I'm using Express, cors, and helmet for my app. Vue3 is used on the client-side only and the library file is self-hosted in the public folder. I simply do

```
<script type="module" src="/public/lib/vue.esm-browser.js"></script>
```

to add the module to the client-side. The problem is that when I use it, it keeps giving me an `Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'"`. This problem started yesterday suddenly, when I started using the helmet and cors modules, and even if I comment out these modules, it still shows the error. What should I fix?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, vue.js uses a piece of code [like this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/d52fbff7a77d8d9c032a74a21c34e2c122add5d9/src/compiler/to-function.ts#L35-L49):

```js
// detect possible CSP restriction
try {
  new Function('return 1')
} catch (e: any) {
  if (e.toString().match(/unsafe-eval|CSP/)) {
    warn(
      'It seems you are using the standalone build of Vue.js in an ' +
      'environment with Content Security Policy that prohibits unsafe-eval. ' +
      'The template compiler cannot work in this environment. Consider ' +
      'relaxing the policy to allow unsafe-eval or pre-compiling your ' +
      'templates into render functions.'
    )
  }
}
```

Here you have 2 options:

1. usage of precompiled templates, see [discussion at github](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-hud/issues/85).
2. using a `vue.runtime.js` runtime version instead of `vue.js` full version.

VueJS has 2 different versions: the full version and the runtime version. 'unsafe-eval' is only needed for the full version of VueJS; the runtime version doesn't need it. See details [here](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-csp/issues/40).

The runtime-only build is fully CSP-compliant. When using the runtime-only build with Webpack + vue-loader or Browserify + vueify, your templates will be precompiled into render functions which work perfectly in CSP environments. See details in [Vue CSP environments](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CSP-environments).

Comment: Maybe worth specifying that 1 and 2 are the same option.  Without precompiled templates the runtime build of Vue won’t do much for you