# VUE3 CSP issue at "new Function"

Tags: vuejs3, content-security-policy

I am using vue 3.1.5 and vue cli 4.5.0 for special application like chrome extension and get the following error

"Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src chrome://resources 'self'".

in runtime-core.esm-bundler.js

```
function compileToFunction(source, options = {}) {
...
   // compile
        const { code } = baseCompile(source, options);
        // evaluate function
        const msg = new Function(return ${code})();
...
}
```

Is there any way to build vue3 application compatible to CSP?

I have tried these options

- config.resolve.alias.set('vue$', 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js');
- configureWebpack: { devtool: inline-source-map }
- configureWebpack: { devtool: false }

Are there any other options or I have missed something?

Regards,
Pavel

Comment: Hi @se_pavel, have you been able to get working solution for the extension? As I understand, you're trying to switch to manifest v3. I've the same problem with Vue, but did not find any solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Vue uses `new Function` for runtime compilation of templates.
If you do not wish to allow `'unsafe-eval'` in the CSP, you have to [pre-compile tempaltes into render functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68459611/how-to-fix-unsafe-eval-error-with-vue3-for-the-client-side-version/68464452#68464452).

Comment: Hi, thank you for links. I have inspected the result js file and see that all my templates are precompiled, but JS code with "new Function" still exists. May be there are some option that there will be no more templates except existing