# EvalError: call to eval() blocked by CSP when trying to run built Vue3 code

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So first of all, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68459611/how-to-fix-unsafe-eval-error-with-vue3-for-the-client-side-version/68464452#68464452) did not help me. It gives only a vague explanation of what needs to happen, and following the links leads me only down various rabbit holes which lead to Vue 2 documentation, or simply non-existent pages.

I have a Vue 3 application that I have built with yarn. I am trying to access it through a reverse proxy with nginx. When I try to navigate to the correct page, however, I get this in the console:

```
GET
http://localhost:8080/ui
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 4ms]

Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘unsafe-eval’ ui
EvalError: call to eval() blocked by CSP hook.js:1:48209
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval (“default-src”).
Source: ;(function r(e,t=!1){const o="6.0";let i… 2 ui
EvalError: call to eval() blocked by CSP detector.js:1:42364
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico (“default-src”). FaviconLoader.jsm:180:19
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval (“default-src”).
Source: ;(function n(e){let t=1e3,n=10;function …
```

My application is extremely simple, it is simply a single root component called `App.vue`, which makes use of a component called `Map.vue`

Here is App.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <Map :features=features />
      <v-btn @click="submit">Submit</v-btn>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>

</template>

<!-- <script setup>
  // import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'
  import Map from '@/components/Map.vue'
</script> -->

<script>
  import Map from '@/components/Map.vue';
  
  export default {
    components: {
      Map
    },
    data() {
        return {
          features: []
        }
    },
    computed: {
      featuresAsGeoJson() {

        let geoJson = {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
          "features": []
        }

        for (let feature of this.features) {
          geoJson.features.push(
            { "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ feature ] } },
          )
        }

        return geoJson

      }
    },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.featuresAsGeoJson));
            this.axios
              .post("http://localhost:80/summarize", this.featuresAsGeoJson)
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
              });
              }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And here is Map.vue:

```
<template>
  <VLayoutItem model-value size="88">
      <div class="ma-4">
          <VBtn
            @click="clear"
            icon="mdi-shape-polygon-plus"
            size="large"
            color="primary"
            elevation="8" />
      </div>
    </VLayoutItem>

  <ol-map
    :loadTilesWhileAnimating="true"
    :loadTilesWhileInteracting="true"
    style="height:95%"
  >
    <ol-view
      ref="view"
      :center="center"
      :rotation="rotation"
      :zoom="zoom"
      :projection="projection"
    />


    <ol-tile-layer>
      <ol-source-osm />
    </ol-tile-layer>

    <ol-vector-layer>
      <ol-source-vector
        ref="source"
      >
        <ol-interaction-draw
          v-if="draw"
          type="Polygon"
          @drawend="drawEnd"
        >
        </ol-interaction-draw>
        <ol-interaction-modify
          v-if="modify"
        >
          </ol-interaction-modify>
      </ol-source-vector>

      <ol-style>
        <ol-style-stroke color="red" :width="2"></ol-style-stroke>
      </ol-style>
    </ol-vector-layer>
  </ol-map>
</template>
  
  <script>
  import { ref, inject } from "vue";
  export default {
    setup() {
      const center = ref([49.0069, 8.4037]);
      const zoom = ref(8);
      const rotation = ref(0);
      const projection = ref("EPSG:4326");
      return {
        center,
        zoom,
        rotation,
      };
    },
    data() {
        return {
            draw: true,
            modify: false
        }
    },
    props: {
        features: null
    },
    methods: {
        clear() {
            this.draw = true;
            this.modify = false;
        },
        drawEnd(e) {
          this.draw = false;
          this.modify = true;
          let feature = e.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
          console.log(e.feature);
          this.features.push(feature);
        },
    },
  };
  </script>
```

And this is the content of main.js:

```
// Components
import App from './App.vue'

// Composables
import { createApp } from 'vue'

// Plugins
import { registerPlugins } from '@/plugins'

import OpenLayersMap from "vue3-openlayers";
import "vue3-openlayers/dist/vue3-openlayers.css";

import * as Vue from 'vue' // in Vue 3
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'


const app = createApp(App)
app.use(OpenLayersMap);

app.use(VueAxios, axios)


registerPlugins(app)

app.mount('#app')
```

I have built this application with `yarn build`, which calls `vite build` in package.json.

In the link that I referenced in the first paragraph, it is indicated that I must "use `vue.runtime.js`", but I have absolutely no idea on how to do this. As stated, trying to follow the links in that page did not help me solve the issue at all, leading instead to missing pages and various Vue 2 documentation.

How do I "use `vue.runtime.js`"? And honestly why is it that building this application using the most basic default project builds it in a way that is incompatible with typical content security policies? It is just so bizarre to me that this is the case.

After more research I tried adding the line `vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',` to my aliases in `vite.config.js`, so it looks like this :

```
// Plugins
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'

// Utilities
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: { transformAssetUrls }
    }),
    // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
    }),
  ],
  define: { 'process.env': {} },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.jsx',
      '.mjs',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx',
      '.vue',
    ],
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
})
```

But it still doesn't work.